# Адаптация макета экрана для планшета на Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Создавал макет под экран своего смартфона с соотношением сторон 16х9. Для планшета 16х10 макет не подходит. Как обозвать папку layout, чтоб устройство - 16x10 взяло правильный макет. На android.com нашел квалификатор layout-notlong. Это оно или нет? В данный момент нет устройства, чтобы проверить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layout-notlong - для экранов с соотношениями 16x10 или 4x3

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего нет. Другие макеты layout используют обычно для другой ориентации экрана (свой под гор., свой под верт.). В вашем случае отличается только разрешение по вертикали, следовательно, скорее всего проблема в типами измерений.
Посмотрите вот [здесь](https://metanit.com/java/android/3.13.php) все эти типы. Если не поможет, добавьте к вопросу код layout'a, так будет проще понять ошибку.

А проверить можно на эмуляторе, физ. устройство необязательно. Просто создайте в нем устройства с нужными разрешениями.

Comment: Нельзя поставить эмулятор на мой компьютер из-за устаревшего процессора и отсутствия там какой-то .....  виртуализации..

Answer (score 0):

Квалификаторов ресурсов много, но увы там нет квалификатора, который указывает на *aspect ratio*

Полный [список квалификаторов здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) - и там не только про `land/port`

Я бы советовал использовать новомодный `ConstraintLayout` он позволяет достаточно гибко задавать размеры виджетов.

Comment: я динамически добавляю view в gridLayout . ConstraintLayout здесь не поможет